# change in between two audio files with touch sensor

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, pygame

I am just trying to do this really simple thing where I want to play two different sound files depending on a touch sensor. The problem that I currently have is that although the sensor works, the programm won't change the audio file... So, I am clueless right now, any help?
Thanks in advance,
Lola

```
import pygame

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 12, 512)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()


fastbeat = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/fastbeat.ogg')
fastbeat.set_volume(.4);

slowbeat = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/slowbeat.ogg')
slowbeat.set_volume(.4)

while True:

    if(GPIO.input(7)): #interrupt pin is high

        print ('touched')
        fastbeat.play()

    else: # Interupt pin is low
        print ('not touched')
        slowbeat.play()
```

I changed now my code to :

```
import pygame

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 12, 512)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()


fastbeat = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/fastbeat.ogg')
fastbeat.set_volume(.4);

slowbeat = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/slowbeat.ogg')
slowbeat.set_volume(.4)

while True:

    if(GPIO.input(7)): #interrupt pin is high

        print ('touched')
        slowbeat.stop()
        fastbeat.play()

    else: # Interupt pin is low
        print ('not touched')
        fastbeat.stop()
        slowbeat.play()
```

and it works for me, but another question is there any way I could change my if -command so that it would only play fastbeat once and then switch back to the slowbeat?

greetings lola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are playing the slowbeat on an infinite loop - so it doesn't give time for the audio to start playing.

Try this?

```
isButtonUp = true  #was the button untouched?
while True:

if(GPIO.input(7)): #interrupt pin is high
    isButtonUp = false   #button is not untouched
    print ('touched')
    fastbeat.play()

else if (!isButtonUp): #has button been untouched before?
    print ('not touched')
    isButtonUp=true #set button as touched
    slowbeat.play()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Does it change anything if I don't have a reallife button but instead an MPR-121?

Comment: I mean, an arduino who does the same if I am correct

Comment: It should still work the same. The main issue was that your logic was playing slowbeat.play() indefinitely because you weren't setting any flags to check whether slowbeat had already been played or not. If this answer worked for you please mark it as accepted. Cheers!

Comment: i tried it, but I probably did something wrong because it said something like 'syntax problem'

Comment: Now I tried it with simply putting `slowbeat.stop()` and it works now...

Comment: Since you got the syntax problem after adding my modifications it could  refer to a variable not being set up correctly. Make sure to use your language rules when initializing/using variables.